# Как запретить доступ к методу объекта

Tags: java, ооп, swing

У меня есть бин Fit, также к нему есть FitTableModel и JTable для его отображения списка бинов. У Fit есть один метод, при вызове которого должны меняться другие строки таблицы. Короче говоря, некоторый аналог группировки. Я переместил все три класса в один пакет, а у интересующего метода поставил область видимости только внутри пакета. Таким образом поменять это поле бина можно будет только через FitTableModel, чтобы она у соседних строк по соответствующим правилам тоже поменяла значения. Правильно ли я сделал? Или есть другие более красивые варианты?